# Select most recent records using LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a simple Linq to Enities table to query and get the most recent records using Date field

So I tried this code:

```
IQueryable<Alert> alerts = GetAlerts();
IQueryable<Alert> latestAlerts =
    from a in alerts
    group a by a.UpdateDateTime into g
    select g.OrderBy(a => a.Identifier).First();
```

> Error:
>   NotSupportedException: The method 'GroupBy' is not supported.

Is there any other way to get do it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Grouping by a DateTime doesn't make sense.  If the resolution was, say, milliseconds you'd be unlikely to have a group with more than one item in it.  Or is this really a Date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is:

```
var query =
    from alert in m_alerts
    group alert by alert.Identifier
          into g 
          select new 
          {
        GroupIdentifier = g.Key,
        UpdateDateTime = g.Max(p => p.UpdateDateTime) 
          };
```

This will return the most recent records.

Comment: This will return a new object {Key, Date}
Is there a way to return same "alert" objects?

Comment: I'm stuck on your comment here. In my tests I'm also getting {Key, Date} but you've marked this as resolved. How do you get the alert objects?

Answer (score 14):

I've had a similair need. I want to get the typed record back, not a new anonymous object. To do that .First() can help.

```
var query = from alert in m_alerts
        group alert by alert.Identifier into a
        select a.OrderByDescending(g => g.UpdateDateTime).First();
```

Use the OrderByDescending to order them and take the top one with First().  You've grouped them by your identifier so you should only get the newest record for each identifier.

Comment: Had to use FirstOrDefault(), but worked great with that.

Comment: @Joshua why did you need to use FirstOrDefault here?

Comment: If I remember right, I was, in certain cases, coming in with an empty set, and so running .First() was throwing an exception. I didn't want an exception, I just wanted a null to check later.

Answer (score 3):

If there isn't a reason to group it, you could just switch your query up a little:

```
IQueryable<Alert> alerts = GetAlerts();
IQueryable latestAlerts = alerts.OrderByDescending(a => a.UpdateDateTime);
```

Comment: @BlueRaja - actually it won't do anything.  Until you do something with latestAlerts like .First() or .Take(10) no database hit will occur.

Comment: @hightechrider: Hence the "when queried"... Presumably, the poster was looking for a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
IQueryable<Alert> latestAlerts =
    (from a in alerts
    group a by a.UpdateDateTime into g
    order by g.Key
    select g).First();
```

`GroupBy` is definitely supported by Linq-to-Entities

Comment: it's not working, the "order by g.key" is "red" -> "a query body must end with select clause or a group clause

Comment: Any way I need to group by 2 fields "UpdateDateTime" and "Id" in order to get the most recent record for each id