# Using LINQ to filter records in an object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a deserialized Json object that I am trying to filter before processing. The data looks like this...

```
Company     Division    LastModDate   Lot's of other columns/objects
123         1           7/1/2021
123         1           8/1/2022
123         2           8/1/2022
```

How can I get all the information in the original object and get rid of records that are not the latest for each Company/Division group?

I tried this...

```
var filtered = origObject.GroupBy(g=> new {g.Company,g.Division})
```

I don't know where to go next.

If I were doing this in SQL then I would be using row_number and just taking the 1 for example.

Comment: Try something like the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761070/select-most-recent-records-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761070/select-most-recent-records-using-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
var filtered = origObject
    .GroupBy(x => new {g.Company,g.Division})
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastModDate).First());
```

This will select one latest object from each group.

Edit: I'm not sure without a compiler at hand if this will group correctly - your grouping key is an anonymous object, I don't remember if they have any equality comparer other than by reference. You could try using a record instead, records have equality by value of all their properties - `.GroupBy(g => (g.Company,g.Division))`. Or just group by a string key such as `$"{g.Company},{g.Division}"`,

Comment: Anonymous types [are fine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types): *"Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal."*

Comment: Thanks for clarification/reminder @Heinzi. I haven't used anonymous types as much since records became available :-)

Comment: It is interesting that you are using linq with linq on the select.

Answer (score 0):

A much more efficient way of doing this is as follows:

```
var filtered = origObject
    .OrderByDescending(w => w.LastModDate)
    .DistinctBy(w => (w.Company, w.Division));
```

This avoids the heavy array allocation and copying of `GroupBy`, especially since you only care about one item from its result.

Comment: It's possible that the LINQ-to-objects default implementation of `DistinctBy` always returns the first element found, but this is [not guaranteed by the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0), and, thus, not part of the method contract.